# Как подменить url адрес без редиректа?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Мне на сайте нужно при переходе по /catalog/4-maslichnye_kultury/new/semena_ryzhika_ozimogo_sort_adamas.html, чтобы редиректило на /catalog/4-maslichnye_kultury/semena_ryzhika_ozimogo_sort_adamas.html . Но в url адрес должен оставаться прежний. Как такое осуществить? Пробовал вставлять в конец:

RewriteRule /catalog/4-maslichnye_kultury/new/semena_ryzhika_ozimogo_sort_adamas.html /catalog/4-maslichnye_kultury/new/semena_ryzhika_ozimogo_sort_adamas.html [L] # L

но это не помогает, вообще никакой реакции.
Вот сам htaccess:

```
AddDefaultCharset windows-1251

RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/css/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/images/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/upload/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/js/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/mod/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/inc/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/min/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/fonts/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/404.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/basket.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/image.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/robots.txt
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^.htaccess$ - [F]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailSiphon [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ExtractorPro 
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно заменить этот фрагмент на

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/css/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/images/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/upload/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/js/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/mod/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/inc/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/min/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/fonts/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/404.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/basket.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/image.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/robots.txt
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/favicon.ico
```

на

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

чтобы правило обработки всех несуществующих в файловой системе адресов обрабатывалось `index.php`.

Работающий `.htaccess`:

```
AddDefaultCharset windows-1251

RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^catalog/4-maslichnye_kultury/new/semena_ryzhika_ozimogo_sort_adamas.html /catalog/4-maslichnye_kultury/new/semena_ryzhika_ozimogo_sort_adamas.html [NC,L]

# Не учитываем существующие файлы и директории
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^.htaccess$ - [F]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailSiphon [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ExtractorPro 
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```